# What will be the impacts if Haskell uses "!" instead of keyword "not" as the operator of logical not?

Tags: haskell

I'm a new Haskell learner. I do not know much about the syntax mechanism behind Haskell.

In some imperative programming languages, such as C/Java, the exclamation point "!"  is used as logic not.

Meanwhile, Haskell use keyword "not" as "logical not". However, Haskell use "&&" and "||" as logical operators.

Obviously, Haskell avoids using "!" to express concepts of "not",  e.g. "not equal" is "/=" but not "!=".

In another point of view, I guess, if the keyword "module" is changed to "package", nothing serious will happen except altering all "module" with "package" in all existing codes.

I wonder, if one changes the keyword "not" to "!" in Haskell, what will happen?

*Complements:*

1. As pointed by @chi, i made a mistake. "not" is not a keyword, it is a library function.
2. As pointed by @user202729, i did not tell my question clearly. I am wondering what will happen when "not" is replaced by "!". That is to say, when the founders design Haskell and they use "!" to work as logical not, MAYBE "!" cannot be used as array indexing. Then the founders try another way to index an element in array (with []? i don't know). Then something like chain-reacting goes on. Does this change Haskell much?

Comment: What do you mean by "change"? To design Haskell like that from the beginning?

Comment: Related: https://mail.haskell.org/pipermail/haskell-cafe/2007-September/031563.html https://wiki.haskell.org/Unary_operator

Comment: `!` is already used for array indexing. Like all symbolic operators, it is a binary infix operator: `arr ! i`.

Comment: @melpomene All symbolic operators *except* unary `-`.

Comment: `not` is not a keyword in Haskell, indeed none of these are keywords: `==,/=,&&,||,<,<=`. These are library functions. In Haskell, it was decided that all symbolic operators are binary infix ones (except unary `-`, which does cause some issues). Having (more) exceptions to this rule seems unhelpful. About `/=`: I like it, but I would have preferred `!=` for the sake of consistency with other languages. Anyway, I think these are only minor syntactic aspects of the Haskell design, and their choice is not terribly important.

Comment: We have both [unary `-` and `negate`](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/exps.html#sect3.4), and a way to mask or specify clashing names. So pretty much the only change would be another special case for a unary operator. We would still have `not`.

Answer (score 10):

You can even try this if you are satisfied with a postfix operator, but this requires the use of the `PostfixOperators` language extension

```
{-# LANGUAGE PostfixOperators #-}

(!) = not

main = print (True !)
-- False
```

I find this to be quite reasonable, not.

Comment: I am new. (!) seems to be operator overloading? Then i tried:
`λ> :t (!)  
<interactive>:1:1-3: error: Variable not in scope: !`
After loading your example codes:  
`λ> :t (!)
(!) :: Bool -> Bool`
Then I tried:
`λ> print (True !)`
Then i got some confusing error messages:

`<interactive>:72:8-13: error:
   ? Couldn't match expected type ‘t0 -> t1’ with actual type ‘Bool’
   ? The operator ‘(!)’ takes two arguments,
     but its type ‘Bool -> Bool’ has only one
     In the first argument of ‘print’, namely ‘(True !)’
     In the expression: print (True !)`

Any idea?

Comment: Your `GHCi` interactive prompt doesn't have the `PostfixOperators` extension activated. Try `:set -XPostfixOperators`.

Answer (score 5):

Haskell does not have unary prefix operators, so you cannot define it as a library function like all the other operators.

The only exception to this is [unary minus](https://wiki.haskell.org/Unary_minus), which is a specific lexical hack to get around the fact that people expect to be able to write e.g.

```
x = (-y) * 5
```

However this has the disadvantage that while `(*5)` is a "section" (i.e. a binary operator given one argument and returning a function that expects the other), `(-y)` is not a section, it is the negation of `y`.

So if you want to multiply all the members of a list by 5, you can do it like this

```
xs = map (*5) ys
```

But if you want to subtract 5 from all the members of a list, this doesn't work:

```
xs = map (-5) ys
```

Instead you have to write

```
xs = map (subtract 5) ys
```

Comment: So, it is impossible to replace "not" with "!" under current Haskell rules, just because there is only one unary prefix operator "-" in Haskell? This really breaks my head which is filled with imperative programming language. I learned that when overloading an operator, the precedence and the associativity cannot be changed. Is it true for Haskell?

Comment: Haskell doesn't do operator overloading in general (unary - is an exception), but does allow you to define all sorts of operators including their precedence and associativity. Type classes permit functions (including operators) to be distinct for different types. Contrast C++, where there's a predefined set of 38-39 operators that are overloadable.

Comment: @AlohaWorld, when you *define* an operator (note it's not *overload* ... in Haskell an operator is just a kind of function name), you can specify its precedence and associativity with a [fixity declaration](http://www.informatik.uni-bremen.de/~cxl/docs/ZVON/Outputsyntax/fixityQdeclaration_reference.html), e.g. `infixl 5 *`. Also the set of operators is not fixed, you can define an operator named `(*$::$@@^)` if you like.

Comment: In Haskell you can define any sequence of symbol characters as an operator, in the same way that you can define any sequence of alphanumeric characters as a function name. There are also a few reserved operators (like "=") just like there are reserved words. Any operator starting with ":" is a constructor. Precedence for operators is defined using the infix, infixl and infixr keywords and is completely flexible.